# Error analysis in implicit functions

Tags: error-analysis

Say you are measuring the focal length of a lens, you have the equation

$$f = \left(\frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v}\right)^{-1} $$

Now, the  error term would be differential form of this equation , as in

$$ df = d\left(\frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v}\right)^{-1}$$

But if you think of this as an implicit function $df$ is zero.. So how do we exactly do we model the error in finding focal length?

Comment: Is that not an explicit equation for the focal length of a lens?

Comment: what do you mean? that's the lens equation yes

Comment: "If you think of this as an implicit function ..." doesn't make sense to me.  That expression you wrote defines an explicit functional relation $f=f(u,v)$.

Comment: Oh I had been confused about implicit and explicit relations. Now I understand the f(u,v) is an explciit functions of all possible focal lengths we could get depending on however we measured u and v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I define:

$$ \bar g \equiv \frac 1 g $$

then the equation  is:

$$ \bar f - \bar u - \bar v =0  $$

which makes it pretty obvious that:

$$ \delta\bar f - \delta\bar u - \delta\bar v =0  $$

so that errors in $\bar u$ and $\bar v$ have the opposite sign and same magnitude as $\bar f$ in order to keep the implicit function zero.

Of course, when we propagate errors, we don't know the true value of $\bar u$ and $\bar v$, we just have our measurements and their uncertainties. We are somewhere on the implicit surface, but we are not sure. Hence, we pick the value of $\bar f$ that keeps us on the surface (a plane, in this case) and find the uncertainty in the true value by adding the known errors in quadrature:

$$ \delta \bar f^2 = \delta \bar u^2 + \delta \bar v^2$$

where:

$$ \delta \bar f = \delta(\frac 1 f) = \frac{-\delta f}{f^2} $$

so that the proportional error is:

$$ \frac{\delta f} f = \sqrt{\big(\frac{\delta u}{u^2}\big)^2+\big(\frac{\delta v}{v^2}\big)^2 }$$

Note that in the "barred" variables, the implicit surface is a plane at -45 degrees, so it is easy to imagine a change $\Delta$ in $\bar u$ requiring an equal and opposite change $-\Delta$ in $\bar f$ to keep everything on the plane. Moreover, you can imagine random fluctuations being added in quadrature defining a little circle of uncertainty confined to the implicit plane....which is why we add errors in quadrature, under the assumption that any function is planar in a small enough neighborhood (which is not always the case, experimentally).

Answer (score 3):

If you have some well-behaved expression 
$$C(f,u,v) = 0$$

then, at least on some restricted domain, you can consider $f$ to be an implicit function of $u$ and $v$.  Furthermore, we would have that

$$dC(f,u,v) = \frac{\partial C}{\partial f} df + \frac{\partial C}{\partial u} du + \frac{\partial C}{\partial v}dv = 0$$

and so, for example,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = -\frac{\frac{\partial C}{\partial u}}{\frac{\partial C}{\partial f}}$$

---

In your case, you have $f$ *explicitly* defined as a function of $u$ and $v$.  You could trivially convert this into an implicit definition if you'd like:
$$C(f,u,v):=f - \left(\frac{1}{u} +\frac{1}{v}\right)^{-1} = 0$$
but it is $dC = df - d\left[\left(\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}\right)^{-1}\right]$, not $df$, which is equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Error propagation formula:
$$f=f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\implies u(f)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}u(x_i)\right)^2}$$
Where $u(x_i)$ is the error in the $x_i$ measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Given that focal length $f$ :
$$f=\left(\frac1u+\frac1v\right)^{-1}$$
$$\implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{u^2}\left(\frac1u+\frac1v\right)^{-2}$$
$$\implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{1}{v^2}\left(\frac1u+\frac1v\right)^{-2}$$
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}dv$$
$$ df=\frac{1}{u^2}\left(\frac1u+\frac1v\right)^{-2}du+\frac{1}{v^2}\left(\frac1u+\frac1v\right)^{-2}dv$$
$$\therefore df=\left(\frac1u+\frac1v\right)^{-2}\left(\frac{du}{u^2}+\frac{dv}{v^2}\right) $$
 Thus above implicit expression will give the error $df$ in focal length if errors $du$ & $dv$ are known corresponding to the values of $u$ & $v$