# Question regarding error propagation in lens formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, units, error-analysis, lenses

Before this i will actually give a question which i was able to solve and here is the quesiton

[image]

The answer is obviously (4) and since i do not know differentiation is solved it as follows

[image]

This was quite a way to solve the question without differentiation, however have a look at the following question

[image]

When i tried to solve it in the same way it was not solvable mainly because the term has a $u - v$ now because it becomes negative.
The usual solution for this using differentiation is as follows

[image]

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this without differentiation and using the same way we did the first question.

Any help would be appreictaed, sorry for the non usage of mathjax i was short on time to go to the hospital.

Comment: I think the answer in the list is (3) not (4). Differentiation of the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is just the approximation $\frac{1}{f +\Delta f} = \frac{1}{f} \frac{1}{1+\frac{\Delta f}{f}} \approx \frac{1}{f}\left(1- \frac{\Delta f}{f}\right)$, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error analysis in implicit functions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/548678/) and there are [many more similar questions and answers on this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=error+focal+length).