# Question regarding solution of a specific problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, error-analysis, lenses

The question is as follows

> In an experiment for determination of the focal length of a thin convex lens, the distance of the object from the lens is 10 ± 0.1 cm and the distance of its real image from the lens is 20 ± 0.2 cm. The error in the determination of focal length of the lens is n%. The value of n is _______.

The solution in the answer key for the above question is the following,

[image]

My question is why is $f^2$ being used why not just $f$ and where did the RHS come from the terms in the formula are inversed.

can someone explain this solution to me.

any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808208/2451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question regarding error propagation in lens formula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808208/)